# Field and Charge densities in two dimensional corners and along edges

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, classical-electrodynamics

In jackson's book, we can derive the equation as following.

$\sigma(\rho)=\epsilon_{0}E_{\phi}(\rho, 0)\approx-\frac{\epsilon\pi a_{1}}{\beta}\rho^{(\pi/\beta)-1}---(2.75)$

My question is

there are no charge accumulates at the small $\beta\approx0$.

But, if the $\beta=2\pi$, the singularity is as $\rho^{-1/2}$.

For me,  $\beta\approx0$ and $\beta\approx2\pi$, the geometry is the same!!

How can i explain this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The geometry is not the same, they are complementary. The case where $\beta \approx0$ describes a very deep corner, so the space **not occupied** by the conductor is very narrow. The case where $\beta \approx 2 \pi$ is the case where the conductor is almost a thin sheet, that is, the space **occupied** by the conductor is very narrow. As expected, the charge accumulations on the corner are realy different.

Comment: Why in the $\beta=0$, the charge can not accumulate at conductor? It is very strange and confused to me.

Comment: The case $\beta=0$ would be all the space filled with the conductor, but the solution do not give a result for this configuration, because the charge density diverges as $\beta \to 0$. Try thinking that for small $\beta$, the corner is like a inverted edge, so that there's little charge accumulated in it.